# Nested Json parsing using jq in bash

Tags: json, bash, nested, export-to-csv, jq

I need to parse a json file , I tied bash script with jq and not getting expected output .

Json File :

```json
[
  {
    "fqdn": "my-created-lb",
    "status": "Active",
    "members": {
      "10.45.78.9:80": {
        "dc": "NA",
        "state": "enabled",
        "port": 80
      },
      "10.45.78.10:80": {
        "dc": "NA",
        "state": "enabled",
        "port": 80
      },
      "10.45.78.11:80": {
        "dc": "NA",
        "state": "enabled",
        "port": 80
      },
      "10.45.78.12:80": {
        "dc": "NA",
        "state": "enabled",
        "port": 80
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I need output as :

```
"my-created-lb"
"10.45.78.9:80","enabled"
"10.45.78.10:80","enabled"
"10.45.78.11:80","enabled"
"10.45.78.12:80","enabled"
```

I tried below jq , but not getting expected output :

```
jq '.[] | .fqdn,.members,.members[].state'
```

But I am getting below output :

```
"my-created-lb"
{
  "10.45.78.9:80": {
    "dc": "NA",
    "state": "enabled",
    "port": 80
  },
  "10.45.78.10:80": {
    "dc": "NA",
    "state": "enabled",
    "port": 80
  },
  "10.45.78.11:80": {
    "dc": "NA",
    "state": "enabled",
    "port": 80
  },
  "10.45.78.12:80": {
    "dc": "NA",
    "state": "enabled",
    "port": 80
  }
}
"enabled"
"enabled"
"enabled"
"enabled"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you want the key's name, you could use `to_entries` like this:

```
jq -r '.[] | .fqdn, ( .members | to_entries | .[] | [ .key, .value.state ] | @tsv )'
```

Output:

```
my-created-lb
10.45.78.9:80   enabled
10.45.78.10:80  enabled
10.45.78.11:80  enabled
10.45.78.12:80  enabled
```

#### Edit

To get the exact output listed in the original post, modify the `jq` script to be:

```
jq -r '.[] | [.fqdn], ( .members | to_entries | .[] | [ .key, .value.state ] ) | @csv'
```

Output:

```
"my-created-lb"
"10.45.78.9:80","enabled"
"10.45.78.10:80","enabled"
"10.45.78.11:80","enabled"
"10.45.78.12:80","enabled"
```

Answer (score 2):

To get precisely your desired output:

```sh
jq -r '.[] | ([.fqdn]|@csv), (.members | keys[] as $k | [$k, .[$k].state] | @csv)' file.json
```

```
"my-created-lb"
"10.45.78.10:80","enabled"
"10.45.78.11:80","enabled"
"10.45.78.12:80","enabled"
"10.45.78.9:80","enabled"
```

Comment: You could factor out the common `@csv`. `[...] | @csv, (... | @csv)` simplifies to `[...], (...) | @csv`